# How to return all orders using integration token and graphql

Tags: graphql

Is it possible to return all orders for all customers using an integration setup and graphql?

I have found how to return orders for a customer, but in the example it requires generating a customer token which would require username/password which obv the integration doesnt have.

Is this something that can be done out of the box or does it require extending Magento in some way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 GraphQL does not include the order query; you can only access customer orders. You can examine the available queries in Magento 2 by utilizing the '[IntrospectionQuery](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/usage/introspection-queries/)'.
You need build [custom graphQL schemas](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-graphql/) to get all orders.

```
query IntrospectionQuery {
  __schema {
    queryType {
      fields {
        name
        description
        type{
         name
         kind
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```